# How can I get a object to face the Direction of its Linear velocity?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, transforms, transform-orientation

I using the UPBGE game engine and I am trying to get an object to turn towards the direction of it's linear velocity vector.

Here is an example of what I have so far:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kcMonBjGswDR5f4AaEjLs_9SZdvI9VrZ/view?usp=sharing

Video Explaining my Problem better:
https://youtu.be/ewJKZfsRjUo

Here is my code so far:

```
import bge
import math
from numpy import arctan, pi, signbit, cos, sin

# Not USED
def find_angles(vector):
    # Normalize the vector
    magnitude = math.sqrt(vector[0] ** 2 + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2)
    normalized_vector = (vector[0] / magnitude,
                         vector[1] / magnitude, vector[2] / magnitude)

    # Calculate angles
    x_angle = math.degrees(math.acos(normalized_vector[0]))
    y_angle = math.degrees(math.acos(normalized_vector[1]))
    z_angle = math.degrees(math.acos(normalized_vector[2]))

    return x_angle % 90, y_angle % 90, z_angle % 90

# Example usage
# vector = (1, 2, 3)
# x_angle, y_angle, z_angle = find_angles(vector)
# print("X angle:", x_angle)
# print("Y angle:", y_angle)
# print("Z angle:", z_angle)


def main():
#   Basic initialization
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    # The Empty Object that spwan the trails, it follows the owner object off this script
    other_object = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects['TrailSpawner']

#    own.color.w -= 0.01
#    own['alpha'] = own.color.w

    # getting linear velocity vector
    lv = own.worldLinearVelocity.copy()
    if lv.magnitude > 0.5:

        # velocity vector
        vector = (int(lv.x*10)/10, int(lv.y*10)/10, int(lv.z*10)/10)
        
        own['lv'] = str(vector)
        own['speed'] = int(lv.magnitude*10)/10
        own['position'] = f'[{own.worldPosition.x}, {own.worldPosition.y}, {own.worldPosition.z}]'

        # Calculate angle
        angleX = math.fabs(math.degrees(math.atan2(lv.y, lv.z)))
        angleY = math.fabs(math.degrees(math.atan2(lv.x, lv.z)))
        angleZ = math.fabs(math.degrees(math.atan2(lv.x, lv.y)))
        
        # Absolute linear velocity value
        lvx = math.fabs(lv.x)
        lvy = math.fabs(lv.y)
        lvz = math.fabs(lv.z)

        # +Z quadrant 1
        if lv.x > 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z > 0:
            angleZ += 0
        # +Z quadrant 2
        if lv.x < 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z > 0:
            angleZ += 90
        # +Z quadrant 3
        if lv.x < 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z > 0:
            angleZ += 180
        # +Z quadrant 4
        if lv.x > 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z > 0:
            angleZ += 270

        # -Z quadrant 1
        if lv.x > 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z > 0:
            angleZ += 0
        # -Z quadrant 2
        if lv.x < 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z < 0:
            angleZ += 90
        # -Z quadrant 3
        if lv.x < 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z < 0:
            angleZ += 180
        # -Z quadrant 4
        if lv.x > 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z < 0:
            angleZ += 270
            
#       Change the emptys and indicator objects orientation
        other_object.worldOrientation = [
            angleX/180*pi*0, angleY/180*pi*0, angleZ/180*pi]
            
#       Print the Empty objects Orirnetation
        own['worOrt'] = str("X: " + str(int(angleX*10)/10) + ", Y: " +
                            str(int(angleY * 10) / 10) + ", Z: " + str(int(angleZ * 10) / 10))
                            
#   If the ball falls outside the bounds then reset the position
    if own.worldPosition.z <= -100:
        own.worldPosition.x = 0
        own.worldPosition.y = 0
        own.worldPosition.z = 5

# Not used
def vectorTo360AngleZ(lv):
    
    angleZ = math.fabs(math.degrees(math.atan2(lv.x, lv.y)))
    # +Z quadrant 1
    if lv.x > 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z > 0:
        angleZ += 0
    # +Z quadrant 2
    if lv.x < 0 and lv.y > 0 and lv.z > 0:
        angleZ += 90
    # +Z quadrant 3
    if lv.x < 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z > 0:
        angleZ += 180
    # +Z quadrant 4
    if lv.x > 0 and lv.y < 0 and lv.z > 0:
        angleZ += 270
    
    return angleZ

main()
```

Comment: This Q&A site doesn't really cover the game engine nowadays as it was removed from native Blender with version 2.8 and few people here use it. Probably best to ask on one of [these other](https://upbge.org/#/community) sites.

Comment: its cool man, I kinda came up with a solution here is the code for it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MJgg-Bcv3kzmDWVFKeorN8qyb2KEm3Y3/view?usp=sharing